# Saving a data from inner PHP function

Tags: php, curl

I'm using [Rolling cUrl](https://github.com/chuyskywalker/rolling-curl) PHP library to get data out of an API with JSON.

In the Rolling CURL library documentation I tried the following example, which works great:

```
$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$rollingCurl
    ->get('https://www.google.com')
    ->get('http://www.msn.com')
    ->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) {
        // parsing html with regex is evil (http://bit.ly/3x9sQX), but this is just a demo
        if (preg_match("#<title>(.*)</title>#i", $request->getResponseText(), $out)) {
            $title = $out[1];
        }
        else {
            $title = '[No Title Tag Found]';
        }
        echo "Fetch complete for (" . $request->getUrl() . ") $title " . PHP_EOL;
    })
    ->setSimultaneousLimit(3)
    ->execute();
```

and I tried to change it for my needs, and save the data for each "scrape" in an array, but I couldn't find a way to save the data from the callback or outside it.

This is what I tried:

```
$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$rollingCurl
    ->get('https://www.myapi.com')
    ->get('https://www.myapi2.com')
    ->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) {
        $output = json_decode($request->getResponseText());
        $data[$x++] = $output; //How do I save it outside this function?
    })
    ->setSimultaneousLimit(3)
    ->execute();
//Can I get the content of each API call without the callback?
print_r($data); // returns nothing :(
```

**So my questions are:**

1. How do I save **data array** outside this function?
2. Can I get the content of each API call without the callback (after the execution)?

Answer (score 2):

I think initializing `$data` and `use` it inside the callback Closure should solve your problem. Without that your `$data` array is only set in the scope of your Closure (note the `use (&$data)` when declaring your callback function):

```
/** IMPORTANT **/
$data = array();
/***************/

$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$rollingCurl
    ->get('https://www.myapi.com')
    ->get('https://www.myapi2.com')
    ->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) use (&$data) {
        $output = json_decode($request->getResponseText());
        $data[$x++] = $output;
    })
    ->setSimultaneousLimit(3)
    ->execute();
// Yes, you can!
print_r($data);
```

Another nice feature I like is the Closure scope binding, just a quick and untested example (let me know when you need more on that :)):

```
class CurlHandler {
    $data = array();
    public function processOutput($data) {
        // Do something with the data retrieved here
        $this->data[] = $data;
    }
    public function getData() { return $this->data; }
}

$curlResponseHandler = new CurlHandler();

// Your callback to be passed into \RollingCurl\RollingCurl::setCallback()
$closure = function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) {
    $output = json_decode($request->getResponseText());
    $this->processOutput($output);
}

// Bind your callback Closure to your CurlHandler scope
// => the scope binding makes $this inside your callback Closure refer to your CurlHandler instance
$closure->bindTo($curlResponseHandler);

$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$rollingCurl
    ->get('https://www.myapi.com')
    ->get('https://www.myapi2.com')
    ->setCallback($closure)
    ->setSimultaneousLimit(3)
    ->execute();

// Get all your outputs from your CurlHandler class now:
print_r($curlResponseHandler->getData());
```

Or last but not least just construct a callback directly on your CurlHandler class which might be my favourite in this case:

```
class CurlHandler {
    $data = array();
    public function processOutput(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) {
        $output = json_decode($request->getResponseText());
        $this->data[] = $output;
    }
    public function getData() { return $this->data; }
}

$curlResponseHandler = new CurlHandler();

$rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
$rollingCurl
    ->get('https://www.myapi.com')
    ->get('https://www.myapi2.com')
    ->setCallback(array($curlResponseHandler, 'processOutput'))
    ->setSimultaneousLimit(3)
    ->execute();

// Get all your outputs from your CurlHandler class now:
print_r($curlResponseHandler->getData());
```

The last option assumes that `setCallback()` accepts callables in general and not only `Closure`s.

Hope that helps, cheers!